# "SaveAS" macro in excel with password protection

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Hi I have this macro in excel file:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:="C:\SAP Imports\Sales Orders\" & Range("A1") & ".xlsm", FileFormat:= _
        xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False _
        , CreateBackup:=False
```

This macro is password protected. Whenevr I run this I get "run time" error and I am not able to figure out whats wrong with my code.

Should I write my password instead of writing "". Please advise.

Comment: Do you mean you password-protected the VBA Project?

Comment: Can't you unprotect the VBA project and then run it?  If the macro is password protected and you don't have the passowrd, then how will you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If the directory does not exist, the macro will fail.

Ensure "C:\SAP Imports\Sales Orders\" exists before running the macro.

Answer (score 0):

I set up a workbook with the same thing and when I protected the macro and placed the password in the lines you showed then it saved just fine.

This led to a second problem, however, when I tried to open up the other workbook.  I then got an error saying that the file was an incorrect format. I changed your line by deleting the `".xlsm"` and changing the fileformat to `fileformat:=52`.  This ended up making it

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:="C:\SAP Imports\Sales Orders\" & Range("A1"), FileFormat:=52, Password:="password", WriteResPassword:="password", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
```

When I changed it to this then the workbook saved just fine.  When I opened up the saved book it prompted me for the passwords that were entered above.

Comment: If you don't want macros in the destination book then change the format to 51 for your normal .xlsx workbook

Comment: Also, if it's not already included in the rest of your macro you might consider adding the `Application.DisplayAlerts = False/True` lines to bypass having to deal with the prompts.