# Error Message "Run-time error '1004': Method 'SaveAs' of object'_Workbook' failed" when saving with VBA password protection on

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save a single sheet from a workbook as a .txt file- the code I have to do this is:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
directory & Application.UserName & "_" & file_name _
, FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText, CreateBackup:=False
```

(directory and file-name are defined earlier in the macro)

The macro that contains this code is password protected. When the macro is run without entering the password, I receive the error message "Run-time error '1004': Method 'SaveAs' of object'_Workbook' failed" . When I open up visual basic and enter the password, the macro runs fine with no error messages. Is there a different syntax I can use to save the .txt file, or does anyone know what could be causing this error?

I found an old help post on another site from 2006, with 0 answers:

https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/567235-error-when-save-as-csv-with-vba-password-protection-on.html

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible (unhelpful) duplicate of [“SaveAS” macro in excel with password protection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8247735/11683)

Comment: Do you define the file extension in the file name explicitly?

Comment: I would say this is Excel failing to realize early enough that saving in a text-only format discards the VBA project anyway, so it's fine that you don't have a password to it.

Comment: @Plutian- Yes, I have the file name as a string earlier, with a file extension of  ".txt".

Comment: @GSerg - Thanks for the quick response! I didn't see a clear resolution to the earlier post,  or an explanation as to why a vba project password would stop the macro saving a file (if the target directory does not exist then surely a vba project password wouldn't make a difference?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if answering my own question is allowed or is the correct thing to do - but I managed to get the macro working and hopefully this will help someone else in the future:

Instead of:

`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
directory & Application.UserName & "_" & file_name _
, FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText, CreateBackup:=False`

Use:

`ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=direct & file_name, FileFormat:=xlText`

Not sure why this works and the previous code doesn't but it will save a .txt file even when the vba is password protected.